# Underline text in web page?

Tags: firefox, website, html

When reading web pages it would be a nice feature to be able to underline text from a page. Is there any possibility to achieve this in browsers (Firefox, IE, Chrome etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 addons on firefox has this a similar ability.

```
Scrap Book   
 https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427/?collection_uuid=c37b85ec-f029-9ef1-1801-0e1ea52ca728

Wired-Marker   
 https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6219/
```

Both have different plus and minus points, so it'll be up to you to see which one you like the most.
I personally use Wired-Marker, can mark text in different colours which is the most useful function for me. Although I do put a lot of my research stuff into OneNote

Comment: I've used Wired-Marker - very good, but it could be a bit overkill for some tasks IMHO.

Comment: both links above obsolete meanwhile, unfortunatelly